# Prolog. Operaciones con nodos

Tags: prolog, árboles, árboles-binarios

Buenas,

Me gustaría saber cómo podría intercambiar todos los nodos en un árbol binario en **prolog**, de manera que

Si tenemos un árbol de esta forma:

```
[[[[[],1,[]],5,[]],
7,
[[],3,[[],4,[]]]],
6,
[[[],10,[]],
8,
[[[],9,[]],11,[[],2,[]]]]]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sólo puedo usar siguientes constructores y selectores del tipo abstracto de dato.

```
vacio([]).
raiz([_,N,_], N).
hi([HI,_,_],HI).
hd([_,_,HD],HD).
hazarbol(R,HI,HD,[HI,R,HD}).
```

Entonces ¿Cómo puedo definir un predicado que intercambie el hijo izquierdo por el hijo derecho en todos los niveles de manera que `intercambia(A4,B).`

```
B=[[[[[],2,[]],11,[[],9,[]]],8,[[],10,[]]],6,[[[[],4,[]],3,[]],7,[[],5,[[],1,[]]]]]
```

Gracias